# Cannot connect tor, Identity key mismatch

Tags: configuration, relays, bridge, bootstrapping

I tried connecting to tor, but I'm getting a identity key mismatch and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
Jun 21 19:43:06.202 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
Jun 21 19:43:06.202 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jun 21 19:43:06.202 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jun 21 19:43:06.208 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jun 21 19:43:06.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Jun 21 19:43:06.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Jun 21 19:43:06.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
Jun 21 19:43:06.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors.
Jun 21 19:44:07.000 [warn] Tried connecting to router at 5.196.23.64:9001, but identity key was not as expected: wanted 775B0FAFDE71AADC23FFC8782B7BEB1D5A92733E but got D0126DE81EC8DBEF93CCF353EA9D20ACB07C7A7D.
Jun 21 19:44:13.000 [warn] Tried connecting to router at 144.76.14.145:143, but identity key was not as expected: wanted 14419131033443AE6E21DA82B0D307F7CAE42BDB but got D0126DE81EC8DBEF93CCF353EA9D20ACB07C7A7D.
Jun 21 19:44:24.000 [warn] Tried connecting to router at 91.121.230.212:9001, but identity key was not as expected: wanted DE684E6C6B7773B8BE74B4D941E4178988E15E26 but got D0126DE81EC8DBEF93CCF353EA9D20ACB07C7A7D.
Jun 21 19:45:41.000 [warn] Tried connecting to router at 144.76.70.41:9001, but identity key was not as expected: wanted A5EABCD79338A1796A4147C87C05941FBADA0699 but got D0126DE81EC8DBEF93CCF353EA9D20ACB07C7A7D.
Jun 21 19:45:41.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors. (Unexpected identity in router certificate; IDENTITY; count 10; recommendation warn)
Jun 21 19:45:41.000 [warn] 6 connections have failed:
Jun 21 19:45:41.000 [warn]  3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN
Jun 21 19:45:41.000 [warn]  3 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state unknown state in HANDSHAKE
```

I also tried using custom bridges but they don't seem to help either.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like some particularly aggressive TLS interception. If you run something like `openssl s_client -connect 5.196.23.64:9001` could you show us the output?